# How to count the number of characters seperated by a special character in a string?

Tags: string-manipulation

I have a string in which a special character is treated as the separator. For example, `str={aA|B|b|Ca|XYzz}`, where `"|"` is the separator. Then I want to count the numbers of characters delimited by those `"|"`. It should produce `{2,1,1,2,4}` as the result for the given example. I can think of using a loop, but what would be a simpler way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
StringLength /@ StringSplit["aA|B|b|Ca|XYzz", "|"]
```

> {2, 1, 1, 2, 4}